# I Need to Simplify an array from an inner join an array php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have an array from an inner join statement from 2 Mysql tables... I need them in a better working format for front end display:

mysql query:

```
SELECT weddings.id, weddings.wImage, images.iLink FROM images INNER JOIN weddings ON weddings.id = images.weddingId
```

OUTCOME:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [wImage] => image1.jpg
            [iLink] => image2.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [wImage] => image1.jpg
            [iLink] => image3.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [wImage] => image1.jpg
            [iLink] => image4.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [wImage] => image11.jpg
            [iLink] => image5.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [wImage] => image11.jpg
            [iLink] => image6.jpg
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [wImage] => image11.jpg
            [iLink] => image7.jpg
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [wImage] => image12.jpg
            [iLink] => image8.jpg
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [wImage] => image12.jpg
            [iLink] => image9.jpg
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [wImage] => image12.jpg
            [iLink] => image10.jpg
        )

)
```

So I need to work this array further to get this expected OUTCOME:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [wImage] => image1.jpg
            [iLink] => Array
               (
                [image] => image2.jpg
                [image] => image3.jpg
                [image] => image4.jpg
               )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [wImage] => image11.jpg
            [iLink] => Array
               (
                [image] => image5.jpg
                [image] => image6.jpg
                [image] => image7.jpg
               )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [wImage] => image12.jpg
            [iLink] => Array
               (
                [image] => image8.jpg
                [image] => image9.jpg
                [image] => image10.jpg
               )
        )
)
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but  a single line of code can get you tantalisingly close: `$data = $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, but assuming your `id` is unique (as I guess), you can use this `id` as an associative key in the output, so you can easily determine whether it exists already. In the last step you reindex the result array. See code comments for further explanation.

```
// $input_array is the outcome from sql 
// $output_array will store the desired outcome
$output_array=[];
// loop through every item in input array
foreach ($input_array as $input_item) {
    // if key with "id" already exists in output array
    if (array_key_exists($input_item["id"], $output_array)) {
        // append image to already existing "iLink" array
        array_push($output_array[$input_item["id"]]["iLink"], 
            ["image" => $input_item["iLink"]]
        );
    }
    // if key with id not exists yet in output array
    else {
        // add current input item to output array,
        // with "id" value as key 
        $output_array[$input_item["id"]] = [
            "id" => $input_item["id"],
            "wImage" => $input_item["wImage"],
            // array with first image, can be appended later
            "iLink" =>["image" => $input_item["iLink"]]
        ];
    }
}
// now we have the result, but output array keys are not 0,1,2
// but the id values (3, 10 etc.), so we have to reindex
$output_array = array_values($output_array);
// now it is ready
var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: Worked like a dream just had to change 1 thing
"iLink" =>[["image" => $input_item["iLink"]]] and boom.. great work, thank you very much.